# When a method is defined inside class scope, project won't compile unless method is invoked somewhere else in the original cpp file

Tags: c++

Here's the body of main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    auto f = Foo();
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the body of Header.h

```
class Foo {
public:
    void bar();
};
```

Here's the body of Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "Foo.bar() called\n";
    }
};

void t() {
    auto f = Foo();
    f.bar(); // If this line isn't here, the project won't compile
}
```

When I comment out `f.bar();` in *Source.cpp*, I receive the following error upon compilation. It's telling me that `f.bar()` in `main()` is unresolved:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   Foo::bar(void)" (?bar@Foo@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main   ...

I understand that it's common to define methods outside of class scope, and indeed the following version of Source.cpp compiles successfully--

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

void Foo::bar() {
    std::cout << "Foo.bar() called\n";
}
```

Nonetheless, I don't understand what's wrong with the original version. It feels like something mysterious and magical is going on that I don't fully understand.

Comment: in main.cpp `Foo::bar()` is called but it doesn't have a body.

Comment: your source.cpp looks pretty wrong. Thats not how you define class functions there. You may get some random overloading somewhere because you declare the class `Foo` twice.

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate the class definition like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original program violates the One Definition Rule (ODR), defined in C++14, 3.2. The relevant paragraph is number 6:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type [...] in a program
>   provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit,
>   and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such
>   an entity name D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - [...]

You have two translation units: main.cpp with all its header files (including Header.h), and Source.cpp with all its header files (which do *not* include Header.h). Both translation units contain a definition of the class `::Foo`: main.cpp contains the one from Header.h, and Source.cpp has its own.

However, the two do not consist of the same sequence of tokens. The one in Source.cpp contains an inline function definition.

The reason for having one definition of a class in a header and *only* getting it by including this header is two-fold:

- You save the effort of duplicating it, and more importantly, finding every duplicate if you have to change it.
- Barring preprocessor shenanigans, with there being only one textual form of the definition, you cannot run afoul of the ODR.

Note that ODR violations are "no diagnostic required" - in your case you get an error, but as you saw, the error disappears if you call the function in Source.cpp. That doesn't mean your program became correct; it just means that the compiler was no longer capable of discovering the error; nonetheless, very strange behavior could occur. Your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: "However, the two do not consist of the same sequence of tokens." This is interesting. I didn't understand that there was any difference between declaring a class separate from its definition, and declaring it while defining it as you go. (Honestly, C++'s design here feels like a trap -- in every other programming language, the style in Source.cpp is *the* way to define your class. And yet, it appears you'd NEVER want to define a class this way. Also, in the book I used as an introduction to C++, ODR was not discussed at all ["A Tour of C++" by Stroustrup himself]. Grr...)

Comment: @AdamEasterling Keep in mind that C++ predates most of those "every other language". You may define the class in the style you do it in the .cpp, but do it in the header file, and make it the only and authoritative definition. A simple rule is that you want the text `class Foo {` to occur only once in your program. Furthermore, if you have a .cpp file with definitions for a class, you want to give it the same name as the .h file (Foo.h and Foo.cpp should be a pair), and you want to include the .h file first thing in the .cpp. Then the compiler will complain about duplicate class definitions.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ODR violation either way, because the class `Foo` as defined in the header, and the class `Foo` as defined in the cpp file are not token by token identical.

out of line definition of `bar` should look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

void Foo::bar() {
    std::cout << "Foo.bar() called\n";
}
```

Note that ODR violations are 'no diagnostics required' 
(this is why one of the examples compiles, the compiler can't always detect ODR violations)

The best way to not accidentally create errors like this is to **always** include the header-file in the file/files where you implement the methods.

When we are talking about good practices, don't forget the include-guard in the header-file.

If a method is short enough to be inline defined, (style may vary, but for me that means a short oneliner), then that inline definition need to be present in the *header-file*, so that the compiler sees an identical type every time it encounters it.

Comment: Just to be clear, would you agree that one should pretty much _never_ define a class in the manner I've done in Source.cpp above?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the C++ standard 9.3.2 (n4296):

" ... **A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, in which case it is an inline member function**
(7.1.2), or it may be defined outside of its class definition if it has already been declared but not defined
in its class definition. A member function definition that appears outside of the class definition shall appear
in a namespace scope enclosing the class definition. Except for member function definitions that appear
outside of a class definition, and except for explicit specializations of member functions of class templates
and member function templates (14.7) appearing outside of the class definition, a member function shall not
be redeclared ..."

& 9.3.3 :

" ...An inline member function (whether static or non-static) may also be defined outside of its class definition
provided either its declaration in the class definition or its definition outside of the class definition declares
the function as inline.**[ Note: Member functions of a class in namespace scope have the linkage of that
class. Member functions of a local class (9.8) have no linkage. See 3.5. —end note ]** ..."

Since `bar()` is defined inside `Foo { };` it is implicitly inline.
I believe taking the above clauses into consideration together implies that `Foo::bar` has local linkage in Source.cpp & is not visible to anyone else. What I find confusing is that calling `f.bar()` changes the linkage allowing your other example to compile.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compiler take the cpp files one by one, there's no way the compiler will remember what else he compiled in another file
2. main.cpp - include header. Header contains a class declaration. `main.obj` expects that foo() will be implemented as a separate symbol available at linking time. Done, write the object file and forget
3. Source.cpp redeclare the class without including the header. As such, the compiler cannot complain of the double declaration. As in the Source.cpp declaration the foo method is implemented *inline*, the compiler (not knowing anything about what main expects) does **not** generate a linkage symbol for the method, Done, write the object and forget
4. linker loads both objects, see that the 'main.obj' needs a linkage symbol for the foo method, searches everywhere and cannot find one - because the Source.obj does not contain one - the compiler was instructed the method will be inline.

Makes sense?